# Solutions not Deploying

Tags: deployment

My farm has stopped deploying solutions. No matter what I try they are always stuck on "deploying"

I have checked that all timer services are running but still it is stuck.

I am looking for other things to check in order to solve this problem.  Thanks

Comment: What's in ULS? How many servers in the farm? Did you try %stsadm% -o execadmsvcjobs on all WFEs?

Comment: Did you restart the timer service?

Comment: yes we have tried this but still nothing. also not finding anything noticeable in the ULS yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post with couple of links. It may help:

[Solutions Deployment Hungs up on Deploying/retracting in MOSS 2007](http://fillzephyr.wordpress.com/2009/05/11/solutions-deployment-hungs-up-on-deployingretracting-in-moss-2007/)